# Perfomance of serializing python list

Tags: python, performance, wsgi

I have some trouble with perfomance in Python. In my wsgi application i'm serialize to json list of class. This is my code:

```
class Foo (object):
    def __init__(self, id,object_id, name_id,name,val,val2):
        self.id = id
        self.object_id = object_id 
        self.name_id = name_id 
        self.name = name
        self.val = val 
        self.add_val = val2


def application(environ, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        q = list()
        response_headers = [('Content-type', "application/json")]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        for i in range(1,50001):
            p = Foo(str(i),random.random(), 'col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6')
            q.append(p.__dict___)
        return json.dumps(q)
```

I got answer slow(about 18 sec). Then i rewrite code to this:

```
class Foo (object):
    def __init__(self, id,object_id, name_id,name,val,val2):
        self.id = id
        self.object_id = object_id 
        self.name_id = name_id 
        self.name = name
        self.val = val 
        self.add_val = val2


def application(environ, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        q = list()
        response_headers = [('Content-type', "application/json")]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        yield '['
        for i in range(1,50001):
            p = Foo(str(i),random.random(), 'col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6')
            yield json.dumps(p.__dict___)
        yield ']'
```

It's run more faster(about 4-6 sec). I can't understand why. Can you explain me why i have this results?
PS i tried different json libs and got same results.

Comment: It seems to me that your second version will be missing a few commas ...

Comment: I don't know how the `json.dumps` is implemented, but I imagine that it could be a problem with handling a really large string.  In that case, your OS needs to find a memory block that is big enough to hold the string -- If `json.dumps` is growing the sting dynamically, you may be doing this a bunch of times and moving a lot of data around in memory, having a lot of allocations, etc.

Comment: @mgilson it seems to be a problem with the wsgi server, because both functions run very fast on my PC. `289 ms` and `492 ms` per loop respectively

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense.  I wouldn't expect `json` to do something as problematic as I was assuming it must be attempting :)

Comment: How are you taking the timings? Do they include some kind of I/O operation that may take long? Are you using threads? The GIL may cause high latencies for I/O if you have a multiprocessor and mixed CPU-bound/IO-bound threads.